# Is there a substr method in jade template?

Tags: api, node.js, pug

Is there exist some string method in jade template?

Like `subStr`, `slice`, `toLowerCase`?

I can find this API in it's [doc](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade)

Where I can find them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can work with variables in template as is. So it's just JavaScript variables.

```
html
    head
        title= title.toUpperCase()
    body
        p= text.substr(1, 100) + '...'
```

Comment: slight correction it should be `text.substring(...)`

Comment: @avrono, `substring` and `substr` functions in JavaScript are very similar but have a difference in the second argument. This is not important in the context of this answer.

Comment: Substr starts at index 0